# Can "turn your collar up" be a natural alternative for "pop your collar"? And "fix" and "turn down."

Tags: word-usage

Is it natural to say:

> Why don't you just **turn your collar up**?

Does it sound as natural as "Why don't you just "pop your collar"?

And what about "turn down" instead of "fix":
Like:

> **Turn your collar down.**(to mean:fix your collar)

Answer (score 2):

***Upturned*** is the usual term in my experience in Britain. I don't know if ***popped*** is more common in some parts of the UK, or more common in America. For me, *upturned* is more natural, but *popped* is acceptable.

***Turning a collar down*** to me has a very specific meaning, to make sure it isn't upturned. ***Fixing a collar*** just means putting it in the state you think it should be in, and could cover a range of things - even just a slightly uneven turn at the back. It is a less specific term.

Comment: "Popping the collar" is indeed a common North American term, often with a strongly negative connotation. For many "popping your collar" is clear sign of someone from the elitist "[preppy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preppy)" culture of private north eastern US universitites and colleges.

Comment: @fred2 Though I note from some reading that it's been adopted by some urban 'poor' subcultures as well.

Comment: A bit like the British 'casuals' of the 1980s.

Comment: @fred2: Likely, albeit otherwise very different subcultures.

Comment: This made me think of [*shoot your cuffs*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/shoot_one's_cuffs).